# get xhr status from a callback function

Tags: javascript, php, callback, jsonp

I have a php call that write javascript lines in my html file in this format:

```
<script src="http://localhost/listing.php?jsonp=thecallbak"></script>
```

I would like to get, in the callback function, the http status (such as 404, 403) to respond appropriately.

I tried several option but nothing seems to work, among which:
 - xhr.status
 - passing the handle in the callback

Thank you!

**EDIT - FOUND A SOLUTION:**

First, add a event listener to you script:

```
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = url;
    if (s.addEventListener) {
        s.addEventListener('error', function (evt) {
            if (evt) evt.stopPropagation();
            callback('');
        }, false);
    }
h.appendChild(s);
```

This allow to receive an empty callback, even when 404 error.

Then, you just have to get the `this.fromurl` in the callback to know where was the 404 (or other) error

Thank you all for your help

Comment: Show people what have you tried and what you've get. For now your answer seems like "stack overflow, do my work for me"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to programatically determine the HTTP status code of the response received by loading a script using a script element.

Use XMLHttpRequest if you need that information.

Comment: Thank you for you help, unfortunately I figured out that with JSONP you can't obtain the HTTP status code... but I think I found some a solution that fits my need (see Edits above). Thanks again